# What command would I use to expire keys in Redis that have less than 5 days to live?

Tags: lua, redis, ttl

Sessions in my db are being set as a hash:

```
1) "sid:lpg3um654ckqp7tj7fkr2qs2Zz" (this has a ttl of a week)
2) "sid:lpg3um654ckqp7tj7fkr2qs2Yy" (this has a ttl of 6 days)
3) "sid:g6sftph5dnun5bk6l0hqyyh6p5" (this has a ttl of 5 days)
4) "sid:g6sftph5dnun5bk6l0hqyxh6x3" (this has a ttl of 4 days)
5) "sid:g6sftph5dnun5bk6l0hqyxh4t1" (this has a ttl of 3.5 days)
```

I know you can set a ttl on a single key from the command line, but how would you do that for a batch of keys that are going to expire in a certain period of time (i.e. less than 5 days ttl). Running said command should result in deleting entries 4 and 5.

Comment: How is that related to Lua?

Comment: ya you're right i thought i was going to incorporate EVAL but my Lua scripting is subpar and settled for sh. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a Lua script (must... honor... the... tag...) that uses `DEL` to remove the sid:'s according to your definition (despite my comment re. `KEYS`'s use, since Lua scripts are atomic there's no need to `SCAN` here and `DEL` won't work anyway since `SCAN` is random) and returns the names of deleted keys:

```
local exp=ARGV[1] * 60 * 60 * 24;
local exs={};
local keys=redis.call('keys', 'sid:*');

for _,v in next,keys,nil do
  local ttl=redis.call('ttl', v);
  if ttl < exp then
    redis.call('del', v);
    exs[#exs + 1] = v;
  end
end

return exs;
```

**Note**: this script is anything by safe to use and could probably kill your production instance (not to mention it not being cluster safe) ;)

Comment: I don't think it's atomicity which makes KEYS undesirable, it's that KEYS (as the documentation says) "may block the server for a long time (even several seconds) when called against big collections of keys or elements". In which case SCAN is still strongly advised.

Comment: Since Lua is blocking by itself, there's little difference in terms of "blockage period" between doing KEYS and looping over an entire SCAN inside that script. Note 1: SCAN's advantage in this case is its lower requirement of RAM (with KEYS the entire reply is stored until done). Note 2: SCAN in Lua is only possible if no writes happen - since the objective here is to DEL, SCAN can't be used.

Comment: Revisiting my original arguments - one benefit of SCAN is that it won't take as much RAM as KEYS' response. However, using it (SCAN) inside of a Lua script is not permitted if you're also writing (i.e. DEL), so no easy solution here.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
FIVEDAYS=432000

redis-cli KEYS  "*" |
while read LINE;
do TTL=`redis-cli ttl $LINE `;
  if [ $TTL -le $FIVEDAYS ]; 
      then `redis-cli expire $LINE 5`;
      echo "Deleted $LINE";
  fi;
done;
```

Comment: Nice.sh - however, KEYS is a command that you don't want to use in production. If you have 2.8 - use SCAN instead.